# Van Kampen three series convergence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

In this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371464?refreqid=excelsior%3Aef6ed6a8e3755e16c2b09a2fb9974f86&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) Van Kampen states the necessary and sufficient condition for absolute convergence of the series $$\sum |X_n|$$, namely that $$ \sum P(|X_n|>c) $$ and $$ \sum E(|X_n^{c}|)$$ converge.

The proof should be fairly similar to Kolmogorov's three series, apart from omitting the requirement that $ \sum Var(|X_n^{c}|) $ also converges.

I am not sure I see how to prove Van Kampen's conditions and why they hold without needing convergence of the variance for the truncated series.

Thanks!

Comment: Are $X_n$'s independent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the $\{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables, then

\begin{gather*}
 \sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>c)<\infty, \tag{1}\\
 \sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{E}|X_n^c|< \infty  \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
are the necessary and sufficent condition for absolute convergence of the series
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{n\ge 1}|X_n|<\infty \qquad \text{a.s.}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where $c$ may be any constant in $(0,\infty)$. The proof of sufficiency is given in the following
($X_n^c=(X_nI_{(|X_n|\le c)}$).

\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>c)<\infty \implies
     \mathsf{P}(\{|X_n|>c\}\; \text{ i.o.})=0 \\ 
    &\quad\implies
    \mathsf{P}(\{|X_n|\ne|X_n^c|\}\;\text{ i.o.})=0,\tag{4}\\
    &\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{E}[|X_n^c|]<\infty \implies
     \sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{E}|X_n^c|^2<\infty \quad (\mathsf{E}|X_n^c|^2\le c\mathsf{E}|X_n^c|)\\
     &\quad\implies \sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{Var}[|X_n^c|]<\infty \quad (\mathsf{Var}[|\xi|]\le \mathsf{E}|\xi|^2 ) \\
     &\quad\implies \sum_{n\ge 1}(|X_n^c|-\mathsf{E}|X_n^c|) \quad \text{convergence a.s.}\\ & \qquad\qquad(\text{by Kolmogorov  theorem})\\
     & \quad\implies \sum_{n\ge 1}|X_n^c|<\infty\qquad \text{a.s.} \quad \text{by (2)}\\
     & \quad\implies \sum_{n\ge 1}|X_n|<\infty \qquad \text{a.s.} \quad \text{by (4)}
\end{align*}